# Fringe field effect in cylinder conductivity cell

Tags: electricity

In a coaxial cylinder conductivity cell with the inner electrode electrified and a dielectric liquid between them, how is the fringe field effect dealt with? Is the effect as severe as in a parallel plate cell and if a guard electrode is used where is it placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cylinder was infinitely long you would not have any fringe effect. You can change the geometry to make the cylinder arbitrarily long so the fringe effects can be reduced, as with parallel plates you can make the plates arbitrarily large, but the dimensions result in volume and materials increasing proportional to the length for a cylinder and proportional to the square of the plate dimension (square being optimal).

The guard electrodes would be placed at the ends of the cylinder, such that current virtually only flows radially.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You say I can make it arbitrarily long to limit the effect, is there any way I can measure it, is there a relationship you know of I can use to determine how long to make it and what the effect would be? Also for the guard electrodes, how would you place it at the ends when on one end you need to connect the cylinders (one to voltage source and other to electrometer) and on the other, you need space to insert the liquid into the cell? Would you create holes in the guard electrode?

Comment: I would suggest using your favorite field solver software. You drive the guards to minimize the voltage difference so current does not flow axially, as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, sorry for pestering but i have one more question. What do you mean by 'driving the guards'? I'm not familiar with the term "driving" in this context.

Comment: You keep it at the same potential as the measuring electrode other by driving it actively with an amplifier or by driving the measuring electrode actively to the same potential and connecting the guard to some known potential (eg. ground). But my understanding is usually conductivity cells are not precisely calculated but are primarily calibrated so fringe effects are not that important if they are stable.